# Dual Monitor Setup, mouse stuck from one monitor to another

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors

I am trying to setup my dual monitors on my desktop (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS).

I have 2 video cards on my computer an Nvidia and an Intel (built-in), one monitor is plugged into the Nvidia (via DVI) and another monitor is plugged into the Intel (display port).

In my opinon, my screens are detected and setup properly. The "Displays" application shows me the name of my monitors.

The problem that I ran into is that I cannot move my mouse from one monitor to another. I can move a window from one monitor to another (half way) but once my mouse is at the edge of right monitor, the mouse will get stuck and I won't be able to move the entire window to the other screen.

Anything I can do to fix this?

Thanks.